# drop duplicates in list within data frames python

Tags: python, dataframe, list, series, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe that I have grouped with textbook ISBN and I the schools, state and grades that those books are used in. I want to remove the duplicates within the lists of the dataframe. I have tried the following steps within the screenshots for the state column as a test but Im not sure if its a list or a dataframe or a series as I tried number of code to see if any will work. Was wondering if someone can explain the structure of these "list" within a dataframe and any code to drop the duplicates.[step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZWfJ.png)[step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PJdu.png)[step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tc32.png)[step4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUINS.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The `df['State']` is a `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` data type. But, each element of this series is a list, as you converted it during aggregation. Therefore, when you `.apply()` the `lambda` on the `df['State']`, it sees each `x` as a list.

You can `.apply()` the `lambda x: list(set(x))))` instead of `lambda x: x.drop_duplicates()`. It will do the same job - removing duplicates.

Sample example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "val": [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
        "data": ["X", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X"],
    }
)

df = df.groupby(["val"]).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
print(type(df["data"]))
print((df["data"].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
val
1    [Y, X]
2       [X]
3       [X]
4       [X]
Name: data, dtype: object
```